# Looking for Xubuntu 10.10

Tags: ubuntu-10.10, xubuntu

I am trying to find a 64 bit ISO of Xubuntu 10.10 .. .according to their site (http://xubuntu.org/news/10-10-release/) it should be released however, I am unable to find anywhere one iso..

Do you have any idea where is one?

Thanks
f.

Comment: Xubuntu 10.10 has already reached its end of life. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Install it on a 10 year old computer :) From the first series with a 64 bit CPU...

Comment: Wouldn't Xubuntu 11.10 or 12.04 be good enough? They are currently supported and you are better off with them anyway.

Comment: They might work too. Our solution was developed on 10.10 (32 bit although) so we know for sure it will compile and work on it. However I might give a test drive to more recent ones...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can download from here:

http://mirror.iawnet.sandia.gov/ubuntu-iso/CDs-Xubuntu/10.10/release/

there might be other mirrors as well.